# Why would create table fail via python but succeed on cli?

Tags: python, mysql, create-table

Here's a question for you mysql + python folks out there.

Why does this mysql sql sequence of commands not work when I execute it through Python, but it does when I execute it via the mysql CLI?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import oursql as mysql
import sys, traceback as tb
import logging

# some other stuff...

class MySqlAuth(object):
    def __init__(self, host = None, db = None, user = None, pw = None, port = None):
        self.host = 'localhost' if host is None else host
        self.db = 'mysql' if db is None else db
        self.user = 'root' if user is None else user
        self.pw = pw
        self.port = 3306 if port is None else port

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        auth_dict = dict()
        auth_dict['host'] = self.host
        auth_dict['user'] = self.user
        auth_dict['passwd'] = self.pw
        auth_dict['db'] = self.db
        auth_dict['port'] = self.port
        conn = mysql.connect(**auth_dict)
        cur = conn.cursor(mysql.DictCursor)
        return cur

def ExecuteNonQuery(auth, sql):
    try:
        cur = auth.cursor
        log.debug('SQL:  ' + sql)
        cur.execute(sql)
        cur.connection.commit()
        return cur.rowcount
    except:
        cur.connection.rollback()
        log.error("".join(tb.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
    finally:
        cur.connection.close()

def CreateTable(auth, table_name):

    CREATE_TABLE = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(table)s ( 
              uid VARCHAR(120) PRIMARY KEY
            , k VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
            , v BLOB
            , create_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
            , mod_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
            , UNIQUE(k)
            , INDEX USING BTREE(k)
            , INDEX USING BTREE(mod_ts) );
    """
    ExecuteNonQuery(auth, CREATE_TABLE % { 'table' : table_name })

    CREATE_BEFORE_INSERT_TRIGGER = """
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER %(table)s_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON %(table)s
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.create_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.mod_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.uid = UUID();
    END;// DELIMIETER ;
    """
    ExecuteNonQuery(auth, CREATE_BEFORE_INSERT_TRIGGER % { 'table' : table_name })

    CREATE_BEFORE_INSERT_TRIGGER = """
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER %(table)s_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON %(table)s
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.mod_ts = NOW();
    END;// DELIMIETER ;
    """
    ExecuteNonQuery(auth, CREATE_BEFORE_UPDATE_TRIGGER % { 'table' : table_name })

# some other stuff
```

The error that I get when I run the python is this:

```
2012-01-15 11:53:00,138 [4214 MainThread mynosql.py] DEBUG SQL:  
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER nosql_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON nosql
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.create_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.mod_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.uid = UUID();
    END;// DELIMIETER ;

2012-01-15 11:53:00,140 [4214 MainThread mynosql.py] ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mynosql.py", line 39, in ExecuteNonQuery
    cur.execute(sql)
  File "cursor.pyx", line 120, in oursql.Cursor.execute (oursqlx/oursql.c:15856)
  File "cursor.pyx", line 111, in oursql.execute (oursqlx/oursql.c:15728)
  File "statement.pyx", line 157, in oursql._Statement.prepare (oursqlx/oursql.c:7750)
  File "statement.pyx", line 127, in oursql._Statement._raise_error (oursqlx/oursql.c:7360)
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //\n    CREATE TRIGGER nosql_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON nosql\n    F' at line 1", None)
```

Comment: What's "DELIMITER //" supposed to do? It certainly doesn't look like valid SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the error you are getting seems to be generated by the first `DELIMITER //` statement, you have a typo at the last mention of `DELIMITER` - you wrote it `DELIMIETER ;` - try to change that and see if that solves your issue.

**Update**

You have 2 typos for the same `DELIMIETER ;` - I believe you are getting the error just after the interpreter finds the first one:

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER %(table)s_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON %(table)s
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.create_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.mod_ts = NOW();
        SET NEW.uid = UUID();
    END;// DELIMIETER ; <-- this one is wrong, it should be DELIMITER
```

Comment: I understand that something is wrong with my use of the `DELIMITER ; ` here, but could you show me what it _should_ be?  I'm coming from the postgresql mindset, and this way of doing PL in mysql is confusing to me.

Comment: I thing there's nothing wrong with your use - it's the way you wrote it in your python code that is wrong - you wrote `DELIMIETER` instead of `DELIMITER` (see the extra `E` between `I` and `T`)

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass queries to mysql one at a time; it's up to the client to ensure that the query text is just one valid statement.

The MySQL client does this by tokenizing the entered query and looking for statement separators.  In the case of a trigger definition, this doesn't work because the definition can contain semicolons (the default statement separator), and so you have to tell the cli to separate statements in another way, using the `DELIMITER` command.

The MySQLdb (and other) python api's require no such statement separation; the programmer is obligated to pass statements on at a time to `query`.

Try removing the `DELIMITER` statements altogether from your queries (when passed through the python api).